# Get Parent of same XML Element with different Patents using Pythons XML ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Is there a smooth way to access the parent element of an element

For example:

```
<A id="253">
   <B id="254">
      <Z id="255">12.34</Z>
         <C id="256">Lore</C>
            <S>9</S>
            <T>23459</T>
      <P>9</P>
   </B>
   <E id="257">
      <D id="258">12.34</D>
         <C id="259">Lore</C>
            <R>39</R>
            <N>459</N>
      <Q>89</Q>
   </E>
</A>
```

For the first`<C>` I want to get `<Z>` and for the second`<C>` I want to get `<D>`

Currently, I am using the following:
root.find(f".//C[@id='']/..").tag
and add the id value manually, but I want to do something manually

Comment: `<Z>` and `<D>` are siblings, not parents.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to replace `elementtree` with `etree` you can use `xpath` to find the previous sibling of every `<C>` node

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for node in root.findall('.//C'):
    print(node.xpath('./preceding-sibling::*')[-1].tag)

# output:
# Z
# D
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use etree :(

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the parent tag, than the sibling in the list before C:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("xml_test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

#ET.dump(tree)

def brother (parent):
    a =[]
    for elem in root.findall(f".//{parent}"):
        for e in elem.iter():
            a.append(e.tag)
            
    print("Index C in branch x:", a.index("C"))
    i = a.index("C")-1
    print("previous tag before C:", a[i])

parents_C = []
parent_map = {child: parent for parent in root.iter() for child in parent}
for child, parent in parent_map.items():
    if child.tag == "C":
        parents_C.append(parent.tag)
        
for tag in parents_C:
    brother(tag)
```

Output:

```
Index C in branch x: 2
previous tag before C: Z
Index C in branch x: 2
previous tag before C: D
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
  tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
  root = tree.getroot()
  val = 253
  for elem in tree.iter(): 
      root.find(f'.//{C}[@id="{str(val)}"]/..').tag
      val += 1
```

Solves the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).